# Post order traversal of a tree

Tags: c++, tree

I try to do a post post order traversal of a tree. The nodes of the the tree have an int data and 2 pointers one left and one right. I have a function that gives me the head of the tree. What I do is:
I create a temporary node and set it to be the head. Than what I ant to do is to iterate to the tree until this temp becomes nullptr. So in each iteration I check if there is a right or left pointer to the node and set the temp accordingly. If the node has no left or right pointers I get the value of the node and ad it to a vector. Than I need to delete this node (and here is the problem) and make again the temp to point to the root of the tree. My problem is I think that I can't delete the last node. Here is my code.

```
void postOrder(Node* root)
{
    vector<int> result;
    Node* tmp = nullptr;
    tmp = root;
    int val = 0;

    while ((tmp != nullptr)) {

        if (tmp->left != nullptr) {
            tmp = tmp->left;
        }
        else if (tmp->right != nullptr) {
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }
        else {
            val = tmp->data;
            cout << val;
            result.push_back(val);
            *tmp = NULL;
            tmp = root;
        }
    }
    for (auto& e : result)
        cout << e << " ";
}
```

I try to set to null what this temp pointer is pointing too and then set it again to the head but that didn't work;

Comment: *Than I need to delete this node* -- What does this have to do with post-order traversal?  Post-order traversal of a tree is usually done by recursion, or using a stack.  Your function does neither.  Get general post-order traversal to actually do that job before thinking about what to do with the node (once it's reached).

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie  This is the way that I try to do it. If I could make it work why should I use recursion or stack

Comment: *If I could make it work* -- Yes, **If** you can make it work.  Why are you trying to invent a way to do this, when it is well-known as to how to do this?  There is no **if** if you use proper, well-known techniques.

Comment: [The classic post-order traversal](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7de5ce37aaf4a24e).  Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: IMHO, in *post* order, you check right subtree, then the present node, then the left subtree.  You are not doing this.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Postorder, as far as I know it, meant LRN (Left, Right, Node).  You're describing a "reverse" in-order traversal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer holds the memory address of another variable. That means when you are doing *tmp=null that means it points null now . That does not mean that you have changed the value of its parent left or right child to NULL.

BTW postorder traversal also possible by using your approach. You have to keep track of the parent of last element. But it will be so much time consuming .
Have a look:

```
void postOrder(Node* root)
{
    vector<int> result;
    Node  *tmp = nullptr;
    tmp = root;
    int val = 0;

    Node *prv=root;
    while ((tmp != nullptr))
    {

        if (tmp->left != nullptr) {
            prv=tmp;
            tmp = tmp->left;

        }
        else if (tmp->right != nullptr) {
            prv=tmp;
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }
        else {
            val = tmp->data;
            cout << val;
            result.push_back(val);
            if(tmp==root)root=NULL;
            if(prv->left!=NULL)prv->left=NULL;
            else prv->right=NULL;
            tmp = root;
        }
    }
    for (auto& e : result)
        cout << e << " ";
}
```